# Remove trailing slash in Google Analytics report

Tags: regex, google-analytics, trailing-slash

In Google Analytics, field Site Content report, I always receive two data about one link, one with slash and one non
Like this:

```
/post-one.html
/post-one.html/
```

I want to receive only data of (/post-one.html), then I create a Search and Replace filter:

```
Search string: \.html/$
Replace string: \.html$
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Search string: `\/$`

Replace string: empty string

Comment: Google Analytics told that this Regex is not valid

Comment: if it contains only html links then you could try the above.

Comment: The "regex" on this filter creator is sort of... -ish. In the examples, Google suggests "articles/post.php", so I tried without escaping the slash: "/$" and it let me save.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an extra * in there. Remove it.
You also need to remove the regex Kung fu from the replace string:

```
Search string: \.html/$
Replace string: .html
```

Comment: I still don't understand why my replace string: \.html$ doesn't work? Why do I need to remove Regex in replace string?

Comment: The replace string is not regex, it's plain text, although it may contain "back references" to captured groups, eg `\1` for group 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some of the other comments and some experimentation, I realized that the Google help text actually implies that forward slashes in the Search field don't need to be escaped (so it's only quasi-regex):

> A common use case for the Search and Replace filter is to turn multiple URLs into one. For example, to merge 'example.com/article/CA/planning+your+trip.html' and 'example.com/article/NY/exploring+the+country.html' so that your reports for the profiles for which you will apply this filter will show 'example.com/article/', please follow these steps:

```
Search String: example\.com/article/.*
Replace String: example\.com/article/
```

So I was able to create a Search/Replace Filter with the following:

```
Search String: [^^]/$
Replace String: [blank]
```

And it appears to be working.

Comment: I understand this Filter. Thank you for your help.
In my situation, it's the best to use Behemian's one (answer below).
Because it only changes the link end with .html/ - That's what I want.
Your filter changes everything end with slash /

Comment: Fair point. I should also update this because it causes problems with the site root. ie: ^/$